# Android produce file from external jar

Tags: java, android, file

Currently I'm working on an android app which in its core suppose to produce a pdf file and display it to the user.

Now, I wrote a java library which takes the data to be inserted as an argument to the main function and creates a pdf document.

The java library works fine. I am able to provide certain data and receive the desired pdf file. I want to be able to integrate these two components: the java library and the android application.

Basically I want the library to produce the pdf file and then forward it to the android application which depends on that library. Currently I generate the outcome file in the classpath of the project.

My question is: how do I take the result file and forward it to the application?
I thought about convert the file into `ByteArrayInputStream` and then send it back to the activity component that started the main java library but I'm not sure how do I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to add it as a library or it is just an external jar file..?

Comment: @shobhit I just want to use my existing code which creates the document to work inside my android application. I don't know how to achieve that goal